# Xamarin.Forms: iOS displays the words "detail" and "master" instead of showing only backbutton and hamburger. Android works fine

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this weird issue where my screens on iOS look like this:

Sample 1:-

[image]

Sample 2:-

[image]

You can see, instead of just being the hamburger button it is a text saying "master". Also, the back buttons, instead of just being this little arrow there is a text added "detail".

How can I get the burger menu button back? I remember it was like this at first but somehow it must've gotten overwritten.

on Android, it works fine...

THis is the page (and also here is where the word "Master" comes from). Ive I leave out the word "master" the app crashes on screen load:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App4.Screens.Hauptmenü.Screen_MainMenuMaster"

             Title="Master">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">



      <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image
                    Source="logo.png"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"   
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Grid.Row ="1"/>
                </Grid>
      </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    d:Text="{Binding .}"
                     FontFamily="arial"
                     TextColor="#2a2a2a"
                    FontSize="18"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>



        </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how native iOS behaves you might have to change a couple of things but I can assure you its a synch.

First of all, to turn off back button text you add `NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle=""` to your `ContentPage.`

Secondly, iOS does not have a hamburger menu icon and hence to get it you have to set this icon manually!

So in your Details `NavigationPage` you give it an icon source.

```
var navPage = new NavigationPage(new SomePage());
navPage.Icon = "hamburgerIcon.png"
masterDetailPage.Detail= navPage;
```

Where your hamburger icon is the icon that you want to set.

Goodluck

Feel free to get back if you have questions

Comment: That helped me out a lot. Actually, u can literally just delete the text in the xaml files where it says "detail" under "title". The I only have the back button. I also renamed the title to "menu" and so it says menu instead of "master". I mean, no Icon but still very well :)

Comment: Happy to help, You can actually even change the icon with the answer. Anyway Goodluck!